# Deleting elements from a list if that value is masked in another list

Tags: python, list, masked-array

I have imported data that has the format of a numpy masked array of incrementing integers. The masked elements are irregular and not repeating, e.g printing it yields:

`masked = [0,1,--,3,--,5,6,--,--,9,--]`

And I have another list of incrementing numbers that doesn't start from zero, and has irregular gaps and is a different size from `masked`:

`data = [1,3,4,6,7,9,10]`

I want to remove any element of `data` if its value is a masked element in `masked`

So that I get:

`result = [1,3,6,9]`

As 4, 7 and 10 were masked values in `masked`.

I think my pseudocode should look something like:

```
for i in len(masked):
    if masked[i] = 'masked' && data[i] == [i]:
        del data[i]
```

But I'm having trouble reconciling the different lengths and mis-matched indices of the two arrays,

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure `data` is an array:

```
data = np.asarray(data)
```

Then:

```
data[~masked.mask[data]]
```

This will be extremely fast, though it does assume that your masked array contains all numbers from 0 to at least `max(data)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use set function to get sets of the lists and take their intersection.
Here goes a demo :-

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import numpy.ma as ma
>>> arr = np.array([x for x in range(11)])
>>> masked = ma.masked_array(arr, mask=[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1])
>>> masked
masked_array(data = [0 1 -- 3 -- 5 6 -- -- 9 --],
             mask = [False False  True False  True False False  True  True False
  True],
       fill_value = 999999)

>>> data = np.array([1,3,4,6,7,9,10])
>>> result = list(set(data) & set(masked[~masked.mask]))
>>> result
[1, 3, 6, 9]
>>>
```

Comment: I get an error 'TypeError: unhashable type: 'MaskedConstant'' Any ideas?

Comment: Last edit was incorrect, try the update. Sorry for that!